# open function returns 404 error on python

Tags: python, json, path, http-status-code-404

I am working on a small python project and found myself having to read a json file. I tried with this little script found on the web, but it gives me a 404 error.
I have a folder containing the json file (datasets.json) and the python file which, for some reason, does not find the json one.

```
with open('datasets.json', 'r') as file:
    dataset = json.loads(file.read())
    print(dataset)
```

Traceback (most recent call last): File "Desktop/proj/ai/index.py", line 4, in  with open('datasets.json', 'r') as file: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets.json'

Comment: 404? Can you show the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/proj/ai/index.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open('datasets.json', 'r') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets.json'

Comment: Please edit your question rather than providing details in the comments.

Comment: I'd say that script and json file are not in the same directory.

Comment: @Giuppox If you are using a relative path, and you get an error like this, you should always try using an absolute path instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a relative path depends of the current directory, when you compile a python file the current directory isn't the file's one. Try using an absolute path. You can also transform a relative path to absolute by using os module.

```
import os
relativePath = './hello/world.py'
absolutePath = os.path.abspath(relativePath)
print(absolutePath)
```